# How to make MetroCSS label always shown?

Tags: jquery, css, metro-ui-css

There is an `input-control` having a `label` :

```
<div class="input-control modern text" data-role="input">
    <input name="salle_lib" id="salle_lib" type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="libell&eacute;" data-validate-func="required" data-validate-hint="Ce champ est obligatoire"/>
    <button class="button helper-button clear"><span class="mif-cross"></span></button>
    <span class="label">libell&eacute;</span> // this is the label
</div>
```

The default behaviour of **MetroCSS** is that when the `input-control` is clicked then the label is shown :

```
.input-control.text > .label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -1rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
}
.input-control.modern input:focus ~ .label {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-18px);
          transform: translateY(-18px);
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

I want this label to be always shown even if the input-control is not clicked. I have tried `$(".input-control.text").click();` but it didnt work ! So how to do that ?

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pheromix/3cms803q/).

Comment: I included the jsfiddle in my question at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this css to your page

```
.input-control.modern input ~ .label {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-18px);
    transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `focus`. Who do I know? because you can see that the selector of the css is for example: `.input-control.modern input:focus ~ .label`

```js
$('input').trigger('focus');
```

```css
/* if you want to avoid the animation at the start

.modern.text * {
  transition:none !important;  
}

*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/metro.js"></script>
<link href="http://metroui.org.ua/css/metro.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="input-control modern text " data-role="input">
    <input type="text" style="padding-right: 5px;">
    <span class="label">You login</span>
    <span class="informer">Please enter you login or email</span>
    <span class="placeholder" style="display: block;">Input login</span>
</div>
```

**Update** Demo: [jsbin](http://output.jsbin.com/wafowe)

Comment: I run your code snippet but the span with class label is not shown on start !

Comment: in your snippet I have to click the field to show the label ! it is not my goal ! I want the label to be shown on start even if I dont click the field !

Comment: In my check, the snippet do this. What browser do you use?

Comment: That was because Firefox blocked the `https` links of `metro` resources.  Please check this: http://output.jsbin.com/wafowe